# How fast is the patellar reflex?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, reflexes, bio-mechanics

I have found a lot of content on the patellar reflex, but I cannot find any studies on how fast the reflex is, from onset of stimulus to innervation of muscles.  Does anyone know of either a study or at least a ballpark number for how fast that reflex is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mamizuka et al. (2007)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17140585) calculated acceleration data of the patellar reflex.

Their study measured the reflex generated in response to the tapping force applied to the patellar tendon with a customized tendon hammer. They measured using a tri-axial accelerometer placed at the ankle joint.

They found:

> the time delay (29.6+/-6.0 ms) and the **acceleration time (150.8+/-19.5 ms)** of the speed response were quite constant for all participants.

---

*Mamizuka, N., Sakane, M., Kaneoka, K., Hori, N. and Ochiai, N., 2007. Kinematic quantitation of the patellar tendon reflex using a tri-axial accelerometer. Journal of Biomechanics, 40(9): 2107-2111*